# Calculate the distance two points - from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, math

I want to measure the distance of these two points. Is there an easier way to calculate the distance?  I try by np.select. I know that I would have to do 3 more conditions . This is error which I have :

[image]

I don't know what's going on with that.

This is my code :

```
data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Mijdasckj\Desktop\Projekt.csv')



choices_1 = ['short','medium','long']


if (data['x_start'] < data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] < data['y_end']):
    conditions_1 = [
        ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) < 5), 
        ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) >= 5 & 
        (math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) < 10),
        ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) > 10)]
    
    data['Pass'] = np.select(conditions_1, choices_1)
```

And this is my csv file:

[image]

EDIT :

I wrote these 3 more conditions

```
if not ((data['x_start'] < data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] < data['y_end'])).empty:
    conditions_1 = [
        ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) < 5), 
        ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) >= 5 and 
        (math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) < 10),
        ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) > 10)]
    
    data['Pass'] = np.select(conditions_1, choices_1)
    
    if not ((data['x_start'] < data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] > data['y_end'])).empty:
        conditions_2 = [
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) < 5), 
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) >= 5 and 
            (math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) < 10),
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_end']) - (data['x_start']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) > 10)]

        data['Pass'] = np.select(conditions_2, choices_1)
        
    if not ((data['x_start'] > data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] < data['y_end'])).empty:
        conditions_3 = [
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) < 5), 
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) >= 5 and 
            (math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) < 10),
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_end'])-(data['y_start']))**2)) > 10)]
        
        data['Pass'] = np.select(conditions_3, choices_1)
        
    if not ((data['x_start'] > data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] > data['y_end'])).empty:
        conditions_4 = [
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) < 5), 
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) >= 5 and 
            (math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) < 10),
            ((math.sqrt((((data['x_start']) - (data['x_end']))**2) + ((data['y_start'])-(data['y_end']))**2)) > 10)]

        data['Pass'] = np.select(conditions_4, choices_1)


data.head()
```

Now I have another bug :

[image]

Previously, normally without these 3 conditions, it counted. Maybe I get it wrong this 'if ... .empty ? I added a few more lines to meet these conditions.

Comment: Try: if not ((data['x_start'] < data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] < data['y_end'])).empty:

Comment: It works. What gives 'empty'?

Comment: Here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.empty.html explanation. This property is used when one need to check if dataframe/series is empty (has no records)

Answer (score 1):

you cant use this `&` in python as `&&` in C++ or C.

change this:

```
(data['x_start'] < data['x_end']) & (data['y_start'] < data['y_end'])
```

to this:

```
(data['x_start'] < data['x_end']) and (data['y_start'] < data['y_end'])
```

Comment: Yeah. I change from 'and' to & because I thought there might be a problem here and then I forgot to change

Comment: Beware, Pandas is not Python! The comparison between two Series is not a boolean like a normal Python comparison should be but is a Series of boolean. So we **must** use `&` and not `and`!

Comment: I corrected as he wrote Альберт Александров and this works, but I don't quite understand what that's it means